# Make Master slave process for temperature monitoring system using cloud services

Tags: cloud, iot, kaa, particles

How can we give access to "read" the data from the application build on cloud to other people? I am trying to make the temperature monitoring system with [mesh based sensor](https://store.ncd.io/product/industrial-long-range-wireless-temperature-humidity-sensor/) with particle electron and  wanted to build an application using Kaa development platform which give me the right to edit the library of sensors and save the sensor data by linking to any cloud database and at same time it gives rights to only read the output (from sensors) to my colleagues through the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey if you are able to take the user id password as input in your application then you should use this [documentation](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/User-management/) which will help you to manage the user according to your needs

But I am not understand about the word you use'MASTER' can please elaborate it 
Yes but if you are thinking to create more admin then you can do it by using [this](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/Tenants-and-applications-management/)